# Loosing value of a checkbox when jconfirm is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jconfirm window on which i display some informative text.
I would like to add a checkbox on that jconfirm window, that based on its checked/unchecked value will add value to the target URL( which eventually will be processed with django)

The problem is that after adding the checkbox in the html code displayed on the jconfirm page, i loose the value of the checkbox.

```
$('#credit_checkbox').change(function(){
 $('#hiddenInput').val(this.checked);
 console.log($('#hiddenInput'));
});

$(".popup-action").click(function(e) {
    var target = this.href;
    e.preventDefault();
    info = "<br/><br/><div> What will happen:<ul class='log payback' style='text-align:left;'><li><input id='credit_checkbox' type='checkbox' />Wanna do this?<br /><input id='hiddenInput' value=''>"; //Probably missed a quote here

    jConfirm("{% trans 'Set status to ' %}" + $(this).html() + " ?"+ info, "Confirmation", function (r) {
         if ($('#credit_checkbox').is(':checked')){
              target = target + "/True";
        }
        if (r) {
            console.log($('#hiddenInput').val());
              $.getJSON(target,function(json) {codecode}
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Syntax error with your  `info` variable. Missing double quotes. `info = "` Now that Lain has edited the source code it's still missing `;` at the end of the string for your `info` variable.

Comment: You should probably check your console before posting here and then come here with the error.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not the syntax error as someone else here pointed out, it's because your checkbox is destroyed before you can read its value.

Try attaching an event to that checkbox:

```
$("#credit_checkbox").change(function(){
     $("#hiddenInput").val(this.checked);
});
```

Then you create a hidden input in HTML that will store that value:

```
<input id="hiddenInput" value="">
```

And then you can read that value from the #hiddenInput at any time.

Comment: I have tried adding the change event to the checkbox, however it is not firing up when the event is happening. Maybe i am missing something and i don't see it. I have updated the code with your suggestion.